# Multiple String Manipulation using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area that I will paste some data in for example like so

```
01-06-2019 <!-- mm-dd-yyyy -->
01-07-2019
01-08-2019
01-09-2019
01-10-2019
```

And when I click submit all the text inside the text box to give an output below something like this

```
06/01/2019 <!-- dd/mm/yyyy -->
07/01/2019
08/01/2019
08/01/2019
10/01/2019
```

I have managed to this on python  using this code

```
filepath = ('date.txt')
f = open("newdate.txt", "w+")
new = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        new = line.split("-")
        f.write(new[1] + "/" + new[2] + "/" + new[0] + "\n")
        print(new[1] + "/" + new[2] + "/" + new[0] + "\n")
f.close()
```

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery so wondering how can i achieve that in jQuery

Comment: you wouldn't use jquery, as that has no string manipulation functions, except those available in javascript ... also, in javascript, you can't open a file etc, so, you'll need to think how you can get the content of the text area ... hint: it's `value` is what you want - then all you need to do is learn some basic javascript to make an attempt to write the code

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1):

You can register an `onsubmit` listener on your form and then in the handler, perform your logic of parsing the text area's value.

The following snippet is an example of how to do that:

```js
// Register 'submit' event listener
document.querySelector('#form')
  .addEventListener('submit', e => {
    // Prevent default action so that page doesn't refresh
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the text from the textarea
    let text = document.querySelector('#text').value;

    // Split the lines
    let converted = text.split('\n')
      // Convert each line
      .map(str => {
        // Extract the date parts
        let [mm, dd, yyyy] = str.split('-');
        
        // Return the desired format by joining the date parts with /
        return [dd, mm, yyyy].join('/');
      });

    // Print result to console
    console.log(converted);
  });
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <textarea id="text"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following regexp-replace for textarea value

```
value.replace(/(-)(?=\d)/g,'/')
```

The `(-)(?=\d)` will find all dashes '-' preceding the number

```js
function submit() {
  let r=data.value.replace(/(-)(?=\d)/g,'/');
  console.log(r);
}
```

```css
textarea { width: 200px; height: 100px; }
button { display: block }
```

```html
<textarea id="data">
01-06-2019 <!-- mm-dd-yyyy -->
01-07-2019
01-08-2019
01-09-2019
01-10-2019
</textarea>

<button onclick=submit()>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any jQuery for this just a little regex should work.

```js
const datesArr = [
  '01-06-2019',
  '01-07-2019',
  '01-08-2019',
  '01-09-2019',
  '01-10-2019',
]
const newDates = []
const regex = /(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d{4})/

for (let date of datesArr) {
    newDates.push(date.replace(regex, '$2/$1/$3'))
}

console.log(newDates)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToFormat(data) {
    var _dataSplit = data.split('\r\n');
    var _length = _dataSplit.length;

    var _finalData = '';

    for (var i=0;i<_length;i++) {
        var _dataDSplit = _dataSplit[i].split('-');
        _finalData += _dataDSplit[1]+'/'+_dataDSplit[0]+'/'+_dataDSplit[2]+'\r\n';
    }

    return _finalData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text area value on clicking submit like the below snippet. You can do your date manipulation (Learn some string manipulation to do the formatting. Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

```js
function formatText() {
  var textAreaValue = $('#my-text').val();
  // Do the necessary formatting here
  var formattedText = 'test';
  $('#my-text').val(formattedText);
}
```

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea id="my-text"></textarea>
  <button class="btn" onClick="formatText()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex replace.
Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/J404US/1)

```js
let dates = document.getElementById('dates');

console.log(dates.value.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/g, '$2/$1/$3'))
```

```html
<textarea id="dates" rows="6" cols="30">
01-06-2019 <!-- mm-dd-yyyy -->
01-07-2019
01-08-2019
01-09-2019
01-10-2019
</textarea>
```